# Oracle Golden Gate Replicat : GGS ERROR 171 Unknown data type received <0x54 49>

Tags: oracle, database-replication

I am trying to run an initial load as shown in the tutorial at http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/goldengate/11g/GGS_Sect_Config_WinUX_ORA_to_WinUX_ORA.pdf and I am seeing this error in the REPLICAT process.

I have tried using the SOURCEDEFS clause as well (Even though the source and Target structures are exactly similar), but I run into the same issue.

---

** Run Time Messages **

---

```
2011-04-14 12:02:15 GGS ERROR 171 Unknown data type received <0x54 49>.
```

The only other Indication that I see in the report file is the following Warning message

```
2011-04-14 12:02:15 GGS WARNING 201 
Rounding up LOBWRITESIZE 32528 to be a multiple of LOB chunk size (16324).
    LOBWRITESIZE = 32648 bytes.
```

Here are the other details. If you need any more information, please let me know

```
***********************************************************************
GoldenGate Delivery for Oracle
Version v9.5.1.31 Build 003
HP-UX 11.23 (optimized 64-bit), Oracle 10g on Jun 24 2008 13:43:23
Copyright GoldenGate Software, Inc. 1995-2008

Starting at 2011-04-14 12:02:09
***********************************************************************

Database Version:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE 10.2.0.4.0 Production
TNS for HPUX: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

These are the tables structures that I have created on the Source and Target, as given in the guide..

```
goldenga@:goldenga/>cat demo_ora_create.sql
-- Copyright (C) 2002, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
--
-- demo_ora_create.sql
--
-- Oracle Tutorial
--
-- Description:
-- Create the TCUSTMER and TCUSTORD tables.
--
-- Note: execute this script from the command line as 
--"sqlplus userid/password @demo_ora_create.sql".
--

DROP TABLE tcustmer;
CREATE TABLE tcustmer
(
    cust_code        VARCHAR2(4),
    name             VARCHAR2(30),
    city             VARCHAR2(20),
    state            CHAR(2),
    PRIMARY KEY (cust_code)
        USING INDEX
);

DROP TABLE tcustord;
CREATE TABLE tcustord
(
    cust_code        VARCHAR2(4),
    order_date       DATE,
    product_code     VARCHAR2(8),
    order_id         NUMBER,
    product_price    NUMBER(8,2),
    product_amount   NUMBER(6),
    transaction_id   NUMBER,
    PRIMARY KEY (cust_code, order_date, product_code, order_id)
        USING INDEX
);
goldenga@:goldenga/>cat demo_ora_insert.sql
-- Copyright (C) 2002, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
--
-- demo_ora_insert.sql
--
-- Oracle Tutorial
--
-- Description:
-- Insert initial data into the TCUSTMER and TCUSTORD tables.
--
-- Note: execute this script from the command line as 
--"sqlplus userid/password @demo_ora_insert.sql"
--

INSERT INTO tcustmer
VALUES
(
    'WILL',
    'BG SOFTWARE CO.',
    'SEATTLE',
    'WA'
);

INSERT INTO tcustmer
VALUES
(
    'JANE',
    'ROCKY FLYER INC.',
    'DENVER',
    'CO'
);

INSERT INTO tcustord
VALUES
(
    'WILL',
    TO_DATE ('1994-09-30 15:33:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
    'CAR',
    144,
    17520,
    3,
    100
);

INSERT INTO tcustord
VALUES
(
    'JANE',
    TO_DATE ('1995-11-11 13:52:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
    'PLANE',
    256,
    133300,
    1,
    100
);

COMMIT;
```

I'd appreciate any advice on fixing this issue.

Thanks,
Rajesh.

Comment: Could it be a character set problem? Are both character sets the same?

Comment: what kind of objects are you replicating? Do they have user defined types?

Comment: No, they are the TCUSTMER and TCUSTORD tables as given in the guide. I've created the same table structures in the source and target. I'll add them to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the error is because we have ASM set up at our place.. and I ignored this part of the tutorial Guide..

> Note: When Oracle Automatic Storage
>   Management (ASM) is in use, the
>   TRANLOGOPTIONS ASMUSER and ASMPASSWORD
>   must be set in the Extract parameter
>   file. For more information refer to
>   the GoldenGate for Windows & UNIX
>   Administrator and Reference manuals.

Posting the reply here so that It'd be useful for anyone running into the same "issue" later.

Thanks for all the advice so far.!

Answer (score -1):

check the initial load method of file to replicat from administrator guide of oracle golden gate. I hope this will solve your problem.